# SQL Count Function By Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CusID   Order
3001    Hotdog
3001    Sausage
3002    Sausage
3003    Burger
3003    Hotdog
3002    Hotdog
3001    Burger
```

How I will use this count function?

```
SELECT COUNT(CusID) AS NumOfOrders FROM Orders
```

Desired output

```
CusID   NumOfOrders
3001    3
3002    2
3003    2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need it with a `group by`:

```
SELECT CusId, COUNT(CusID) AS NumOfOrders
FROM Orders
group by CusId
order by CusId;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `group by` will give you that desired result along with `Count` function.

```
select CustID, count(CustID) from Orders
group by CustID
```

Refer below fiddle link for sample

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3827b/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select CusID,count(CusID) from Orders group by CusID order by CusId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm) and [ORDER BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-order-by.htm) in your query.

```
SELECT CusId, COUNT(CusID) AS NumOfOrders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CusId
ORDER BY CusId;
```